# How to use SSIS Variable to construct SQL statement with IN clause

Tags: variables, ssis, sqlcommand

I wonder is someone could help me here. I would like build a dynamic sql command something like this

```
SELECT * from Table1 Where CID > 10 + and LID in (11,12,15,20)
```

for this i have set up two var and set the expression like below

```
"SELECT * from Table1 Where CID >" + (@User:Var1) + "and LID in "+(@User:Var2)
```

The var1 is an Int64 type generated from a single row sql task result set and it is working okay whereas Var2 is an Object type and i have problem in getting the Var2 working in the above statement in replacing "and Lid (11,12,15,20)".

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you receive an error?

Comment: Nice question, bottom line, your Var2 is not designed to work that way. If you can give me some additional info on what you are planning to do with the records from the select statement, we could look at work arounds for this.

Comment: HI Godzilla, thanks for your reply, all i want to do is to build a dynamic sql using expression  on a dataflow task. The statement would include details from two var. First one is a single value which works fine, the second one is a list which i need to transpose with comma as "in (11,12,15,20)". My statement should look like this SELECT * from Table1 Where CID > @@10@@ and LID in @@(11,12,15,20)@@. the items between @@ is supposed to come from variables.

Comment: You can't do diddly with a Variable of type Object in SSIS Expressions. You're going to need to use a Script task to convert the array-like object in `@[User::Var2]` to a string

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is what you are looking for, I am using a table from AdventureWorks as example.

```
Declare @var1 int = 10
Declare @var2 varchar(100) = '(11,12,15,20)'

Declare @sql varchar(max) 
=   'SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[DimEmployee] WHERE EmployeeKey > ' + 
    CAST(@var1 as varchar(10)) + ' AND ParentEmployeeKey IN ' +
    @var2

Exec(@sql)
```

Ignore if not useful.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, is this working on SSIS as an expression? My primary issue is how i can transpose a result set from an object type variable which has a list of values into a something that i can use in IN CLAUSE as (11,12,15,20).

Comment: Did you find the solution Anbu?

Comment: No Yet, but working on using a script task with for each loop container to read list  items and pass it another variable and use that in Expression. It was suggestion from an SSIS guru.. :-) i am half way through cracking it.